# how to convert propel criteria in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, criteria, propel

select a.id, b.title, b.start_time, b.end_time from tv_channel a
left join tv_program b on a.id = b.tv_channel_id and b.start_time >= ‘2011-09-23 12:00:00′ and b.end_time <= '2011-09-23 14:30:00'
order by a.code
limit 0, 10;

–pager object
tnx

Answer (score 0):

What's the question ? Do you want to write this SQL query in Propel ?

```
<?php

TvChannelQuery::create('a')
    ->joinTvProgram('b')
    ->addJoinCondition('b', 'b.StartTime >= 2011-09-23 12:00:00')
    ->addJoinCondition('b', 'b.EndTime >= 2011-09-23 14:30:00')
    ->orderByCode()
    ->limit(10)
    ;
```

Something like that should work but be be careful about values passed in `addJoinCondition`, there is no binding here and if you want to change these values you have to use it to prevent SQL injections or other security issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addLeftJoin(tv_channel.id = tv_program .channel_id);
$c->add(tv_program.start_time, '2011-09-23 12:00:00', Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL);
$c->add(tv_program.end_time, '2011-09-23 14:30:00', Criteria::LESS_EQUAL); 
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(tv_channel.code);
$c->setLimit(10);
$rs = DoSelect($c); //actual select execution here...
```